# Generating a Symbol Similar to \Delta

Tags: math-operators

I know how to generate the symbol `\Delta`. But is there a way to generate the similar triangle symbol underlined in pink:

[image]

Comment: `\mathnormal{\Delta}`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on, i.e., math.stackexchange.

Comment: Is this a LaTeX or MathJax question?

Comment: @George MathJax is not TeX, it only shares (part of) the syntax.